# Which html is supported in Jenkins job description

Tags: html, jenkins

In the Job description you can use Html tags.
I have something like:

```
blabla.. on <a href="http://vms029/wa_shdw" target="_blank">http://vms029/wa_shdw</a>
```

But the `target="_blank"` seems to get scrubbed somewhere.
Is there another way? 
Any doc on whats supported and what's not?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Jenkins allows you to use various markup languages to write job descriptions; plugins can define how the description should be parsed via the [`MarkupFormatter`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/jenkins-1.531/core/src/main/java/hudson/markup/MarkupFormatter.java) interface.

By default, the [`RawHtmlMarkupFormatter`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/jenkins-1.531/core/src/main/java/hudson/markup/RawHtmlMarkupFormatter.java) is used, which applies an HTML sanitisation policy (from the [OWASP AntiSamy Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project)) — the [Myspace policy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/jenkins-1.531/core/src/main/java/hudson/markup/MyspacePolicy.java).

In the Myspace policy, you'll see that only certain tags and attributes are allowed. `target` isn't one of them, which is why you see it being stripped from your input.

For your use case, the alternatives are to install and configure another markup formatter plugin, or to write your own. Some examples include:

- [Escaped Markup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Escaped+Markup+Plugin): escapes all HTML tags (probably not so useful for you)
- ["Anything Goes" Formatter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=60915753): allows *any* HTML input at all (with the associated security risks)
- [PegDown Formatter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PegDown+Formatter+Plugin): lets you write your descriptions in [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) (probably the nicest option here, but likely doesn't support things like `target="_blank"`)

Comment: Thanks, precise the info I needed. 
Have decided to install the "anything goes" formatter plugin

Comment: Those plugins outdated like mammoth's shit. Use [OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/OWASP+Markup+Formatter+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Because I had the fun of trying to figure out what exactly should work, documentation is light on usable details, and I don't want to have to do this again in a year or two, here goes:

Any references to RawHtmlMarkupFormatter are obsolete by now. As a comment said, the "safe html" markup is now provided by [OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin (antisamy-markup-formatter)](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/OWASP+Markup+Formatter+Plugin). The actual tags it permits are visible indirectly in the [BasicPolicy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/antisamy-markup-formatter-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/markup/BasicPolicy.java) which uses [org.owasp.html.Sanitizers](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/master/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/Sanitizers.java). These two references together allow figuring out what's really supposed to be ok.

For example `<font color=...>` used to work back in the day (see MyspacePolicy in the other answer), but appears to no longer be allowed, but enough simple `<span style="color:...">` styles are permitted to get somewhere equivalent. This matches the observed behavior of OWASP Markup Formatter 2.0 on a Jenkins instance.