# How to add new line to description in Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins

how to add new line to description in Jenkins, when I change it programmatically?

I have tried something like this:

```
job.builds[0].description = "hello" << '\n' << "world"
```

and Console Scripts prints well:

`hello`

`world`

but in description on Jenkins, this job has "hello world" without newline beetwen `hello` and `world`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `\r\n` and `<br/>\n`. Does one of them work?

Comment: None of these works :(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok,
I found the answer.

Description is Raw Html.

To create new line, we must write:

```
job.builds[0].description = "hello<br> world"
```

Console will print it as `hello<br> world`, but in description will be newline.

Comment: Note that this behaviour is pluggable (though the default is a subset of HTML): http://stackoverflow.com/a/18867643/234938

Comment: And make sure the `Safe HTML` is enabled. Please go to

Manage Jenkins → Configure Global Security → Markup Formatter

to check your setting.

Comment: So how to see it as a newline in the jenkins build log?

Answer (score 2):

Can use

```
job.builds[0].description = """Description
Description xxx
"""
```

About groovy multiple line string: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string

Confirmed it works on Jenkins 2.332.2

Answer (score 1):

As of Oct 2023, you can simply add a `<br>` tag to your "Description" text to add a new-line.

Comment: Oct 2024, the future is here!