# HTML in Jenkins job descriptions

Tags: html, jenkins

I have two Jenkins instances running. An old (legacy) one at version 1.614 and a new one with 1.633.

In the old one it is possible to use HTML in the job description (it even does syntax highlighting editing it). The new one doesn't. HTML content is escaped and shown as plain text. I could not find a change in the release notes explaining this behavior. Is there a configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at different markups: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Markup+formatting

Answer (score 319, accepted):

In the Global security menu:

[image]

Select this value to display HTML:

[image]

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867232/which-html-is-supported-in-jenkins-job-description

Comment: Thanks! For those, like me, behind a firewall and does not have this option available at the ComboBox...   install one of these plugins manually, like this one: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PegDown+Formatter+Plugin#PegDownFormatterPlugin-install

Comment: You need to Install [OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/OWASP+Markup+Formatter+Plugin) before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder how one can enable Safe Html as a code inside Jenkins configuration? Any examples?

Comment: @ShahnurIsgandarli I'm sorry, I have no idea on how to do that

Comment: For html code(description) in "pipeline(or jenkinsfile) code" check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041201/jenkins-parameterised-build-description-in-html-format?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

For enabling it via config: you have to install the configuration as code (CASC) plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/configuration-as-code/) , and add the following entries to your config file(s - I guess, it is better to have multiple files for a better overview):

```
    markupFormatter:
      rawHtml:
        disableSyntaxHighLighting: false
```

If you don't need highlighting, change it to true