# Jenkins Pipeline: How to add help for Global Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

According to [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/README.md), it should be possible to include `*.txt` file with help/documentation:

> ```
> (root)
>  +- src                     # Groovy source files
>  |   +- org
>  |       +- foo
>  |           +- Bar.groovy  # for org.foo.Bar class
>  +- vars
>  |   +- foo.groovy          # for global 'foo' variable/function
>  |   +- foo.txt             # help for 'foo' variable/function
>  +- resources               # resource files (external libraries only)
>  |   +- org
>  |       +- foo
>  |           +- bar.json    # static helper data for org.foo.Bar
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The vars directory hosts scripts that define global variables
>   accessible from Pipeline scripts. The basename of each *.groovy file
>   should be a Groovy (~ Java) identifier, conventionally camelCased. The
>   matching *.txt, if present, can contain documentation, processed
>   through the system’s configured markup formatter (so may really be
>   HTML, Markdown, etc., though the txt extension is required).

Unfortunately it hasn't worked for me by simply creating `*.txt` with some arbitrary content.

Am I missing something? Or does Global Shared Library doesn't shown documentation in usual Jenkins places: [image]

Comment: Apparently it works just fine, but it reappeared just after first build with this library  completed.

Comment: My custom step's documentation is appended to the list in the 'pipeline-syntax/globals' section for a project which has just sucessfully used it.  However the HTML tags appears as text, and the documentation doesn't say which markdown formatting is expected?

Comment: @simon.watts You need to enable a Markup Formatter on the jenkins security configuration as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33821442/2249614)

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the PipelineSyntax/Global Variables Reference page is ONLY updated when the pipeline's run is successful. And therefore ONLY for this pipeline (and not any others).

Here's [a link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/w2NA1_JyHSw)!