# Displaying announcement on all Jenkins pages

Tags: jenkins, header, jenkins-plugins

Is there a simple way or a plugin to display any custom message on Jenkins pages for all users? I wanted to display important changes or actions directly on Jenkins instead of emailing everyone.
What I mean is to have configurable panel similar to "Jenkins is going to shut down" which I could display and possibly change color. I tried to find plugins for that but found nothing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my dummy question, maybe someone will look for it later.

There's a plugin for injecting code to page header and footer:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Page+Markup+Plugin
It's not as easy to find as it should be downloaded from creators' page (link in description).

Without an extra plugin: **In my case it was simpler as it was enough to add system message (manage jenkins -> configure system -> system message).**
You can add CSS to Jenkins\war\css\style.css and use it in system message. I reused "shutdown-msg" which is displayed when jenkins is going to shut down.

```css
#shutdown-msg {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #ef2929;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
}

#yellow-msg {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: #eded78;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
}

#green-msg {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #34ba51;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
}

#blue-msg {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2d72d8;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
}

#grey-msg {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #6b7777;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="shutdown-msg">Red message</div> 
<div id="green-msg">Green message</div>
<div id="yellow-msg">Yellow message</div>
<div id="blue-msg">Blue message</div>
<div id="grey-msg">Grey message</div>
```

Comment: One remark. "System message" must be configured as HTML as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33821442/1970278

Comment: Thanks for this. I used the built-in shutdown-msg class but overrode the colors. <div id="shutdown-msg" style="background-color: yellow; color: gray;">The Message</div>

Comment: How can I edit the CSS so it will be applied to Jenkins “System Message” string?